# How to architect an efficient background batch processes for a web application?

Tags: php, node.js, web-applications, integration, background-process

I have a web application written in PHP using a Postgres database.

The next phase of development is for background batch processes to be built that will need to be executed once a day (or adhoc as requested) for each user of the app. The process will query, await response and process the response from third-party services to feed information into the user's account within the web application.

Are there good ways to do this?

- How would batches be triggered every day at 3am for **each** user?
- Given there could be a delay in the response, is this a good scenario to use something like [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)?
- Is it best to have the output of the batch process directly update the web application's database
  with the appropriate data? 
  Or, is there some other way to handle the output?

**Update:** The process doesn't *have* to run at 3am. The key is that a few batch processes may need to run for each user. The execution of batches could be spread throughout the day.. I want this to be a "background" process separate to the app.

Comment: As far as running a script at a particular time is concerned then you can always use cron. But is data fetched for all the users at same time i.e. 3am? I mean if there are 1000 users then data will be downloaded for all 1000 users at 3am.

Comment: @suraj it's best to be evenly spaced out to same the load across the day if that's possible

Answer (score 1):

You could write a PHP script that runs through any users that need to be processed, and set up a cron job to run your script at 3am. Running as a cron job means you don't need to worry so much about how slow the third party call is. Obviously you'd need to store any necessary data in the database.

Alternatively, if the process is triggered by the user doing something on the site, you could use `exec()` to trigger the PHP script to process just that user, right away, without the user having to wait. The risk with this is that you can't control how rapidly the process is triggered.

Third option is to just do the request live and make the user wait. But it sounds like this is not an option for you.

It really depends on what third party you're calling and why. How long does the third party take to respond, how reliable they are, what kind of rate limits they might enforce, etc...